How to get result of runCommand() using Scripting API
I am trying to run scoreboard players get list ${ev.sender.name} to get the value of an list called money, but I wasn't able to find a way to get the output of the command.
So I tried running the following:
import { world, system } from "@minecraft/server";

world.beforeEvents.chatSend.subscribe(ev => {
    try {
        system.run(() => {
            const resultFull = system.runCommand(`scoreboard players list ${ev.sender.name}`);
            result = resultFull.statusMessage;
        });
        ev.sender.sendMessage(`Get result: ${result}`)
    } catch (e) {
        ev.sender.sendMessage(`Failed to run with error: "${e}"`);
    }
});

but the code returned Get result: undefined.

runCommand is a method of Dimension, not System.  The CommandResult object that it returns tells you how MANY results there were, but not what the results were.
